# Can't launch iOS 13.7 simulator on Xcode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, device, simulator

I'm trying to run a 13.7 simulator in Xcode 12. I get this error when I try `Failed to start launchd_sim: could not bind to session, launchd_sim may have crashed or quit`. How do I fix this so I can run my older simulators on Xcode 12